# Как правильно говорить

Tags: склонение

Слово головИзна.  Щи с головИзной или с головизнОй? ГоловИзны или головизнЫ?

Answer (score 1):

В слове **головИзна** ударение во всех падежах на одном месте, т.е. неподвижное. Поэтому: ***щи с головИзной, головИзны.*** (Орфоэпический словарь Т.Ф. Ивановой)

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай. Словас ударением на предпоследнем слоге и ненулевой флексией крайне редко имеют формы со смещённым ударением. Я даже и сспомнить-то не могу иавскидку.